# AWS elastic beanstalk application does not show load balancer's ssl certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm not sure if the question fits here, but I hope I can get an answer.

I added ssl certificate to load balancer which connected to my ELB application.

[image: my ELB application]

But in the configuration menu of ELB application, the ssl certificate is empty.

[image: the configuration menu of my ELB application]

The weirdest is the ssl certificate is actually working. But because of this problem, I can not clone my application environment, it gives me `Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'aws:elb:listener:443' (Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443', OptionName: 'SSLCertificateId'): Invalid SSL Certificate Id: ARNs must start with 'arn:':`.

May I know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround:

1. Save the configuration of the environment you want to clone
   [save configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcr6l.png)
2. Launch the environment from the saved configruation
   [launch environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N2N3.png)
3. Remove Listener on port 443 on the Load Balancer
   [remove listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Fpa.png)